# Index & match using multiple searches

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match

I am trying to make a formula that searches a table but has 2 things it need to find to then give an output. One search string works well with this.

```
=INDEX(C3:C33,MATCH("1450",A3:A33,0),1)
```

This works perfect for one query of information. I tried to use `REGEXMATCH`, but it doesn't allow numbers (or at least I couldn't get it). Other problem I have is I am not doing an exact match search on one item. Both query search are column searches, If that matters.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | No | Go | Formula |
| Yea | Nah | Stop | Formula |

In theory it would do a search of column A for "Yea", & Column B for "Na", return the search in column D with "Stop"

Hopefully that makes sense.

I haven't been able to do multiple queries, only single queries in to return the correct result. Tried `REGEXMATCH`, `LOOKUP`, `IFAND`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to achieve a match based on multiple conditions:

> =INDEX(C3:C33,MATCH(1,(A3:A33="Yea")*(B3:B33="Nah"),0))

[image: Screenshot]

Based on your statement "**Other problem I have is I am not doing an exact match search on one item**", I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for.  I am also not sure where the number comes in.

This is just an example of how to do a match based on multiple conditions.  Let me know if this helps or at least gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: That works, I edited some om my search strings to make it work. Thank you.

Comment: Great.  Glad it was helpful.